# My facebook messenger chat plugin is not showing on my website

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I use facebook messenger chat plugin on my wordpress. In the edit page it's showing normally but when open in browser, it's not showing. I followed all the step in the facebook setting under messenger platform and copy the code given in facebook messenger chat plugin. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Showing any Error or check your console

Answer (score 1):

Please inspect or view source code and check if there its installed properly in your website. make sure where they have asked you to put the code. Like if they have said to input code before head then it should be before head , If they have asked you to put before body then it will be before body tag. make sure you did not done any mistake when you are implementing the code.

Google Tag manager is best solution for such kind of task. let me know if there it solved or you still need help.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for responded. It's says "Insert it directly after the opening <body> tag on each page where you want the plugin to appear.". What theme files should i copy the code? By the way, i used code to masked redirect from my website to another domain. It's effect the function of facebook live chat to appear?

Comment: Before Deciding that can you please tell me which platform you are using ? If you are using WordPress then there is a Plugin do that by Google Tag Manager , best option for inserting tag. let me know about your platform.